# Looking for algorithm to compare two directories have the same structures in (c# or Java)

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

I try to compare two directories with recursive algorithm without any buffer(you are not allowed enumerate all file/directories to an array/list, but variables are ok)
I'm looking for algorithm to compare two directories whether they have the same structures(same file/directory names)
    Dir1:
      file1
      file2
      Dir11
        file11
        file12

```
Dir2:
  file2
  file3
  Dir12
    file21
    file22
```

Comment: `I try to compare two directories`, then do it.

Comment: not sure why it is off topic,

Comment: System.IO only have classes to manipulate file/directory structures, not algorithm to compare two directory structures without any buffer,

Comment: You've no effort at solving this yourself, you've asked no specific question about where you might be confused. We've asked you for this, and yet you failed to respond.

Comment: I did try many times, and I found it is not easy question. First you need to understand my question, "recursive and without buffer", try to come up the algorithm yourself whether you really understand what I'm talking about

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "buffer"? A recursive algorithm would be a pretty easy way to solve this problem, although the stack could be considered a buffer (which eliminates **any** recursive algorithm, i.e. you have a contradiction in your requirements). I don't see where else you'd want a buffer in a recursive algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: buffer means "you use array/list to store all the files and directories". The condition here is we did not want to store all the file/directories in buffer, and it takes a lots of memory for large director.

Answer (score 4):

Take a list `lst1` of all the directories in the first directory and a list `lst2` of all the directories in the second directory.
Check if the two lists contain same counts and names of directories (A).
If (A) is `false`, return `false`.
Take a list of all regular files (not directories) in the two directories (which you're comparing), check if they contain the same counts and names (B) of files.
If (B) is `false`, return `false`.

OK, assume (A) and (B) are both `true` here.

Now, just call your algorithm/method recursively on each directory `d1` from `lst1` and each corresponding directory (with the same name) `d2` from `lst2`. If all these comparison calls return `true`, return `true` from your method, otherwise return `false`.

Comment: Downvoter, mind to explain?

Comment: I'm the up-voter -- you gave an algorithm which answers the question, and you didn't spoon-feed code. I have no idea why someone down-voted this.

Comment: Not buffers are allowed here, you can't enumerate all the file/directories into an array/list.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I would like to see the actual algorithm in Java or C#. You answer is and "idea", it is not an algorithm.